# Mysql Sort by Title containing Alphanumeric

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

I have title column containing rows as

```
Plot 2, Plot 3, Shop 4, Plot 2-A, Plot 4, Plot 2B
```

I think this is how it should appear instead:

```
Plot 2, Plot 2-A, Plot 2B, Plot 3, Plot 4, Shop 4
```

This is achieved with the simple query [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b0f32/2/0)

But I cannot produce results having my table  `Accounts` having columns `title, desc, parent_id`

When i run query `SELECT title from accounts order by title`
The result is `Plot 10, Plot 100, Plot 101, Plot 101B, Plot 102A`

While i have rows that contain `Plot 2B, Plot 2-A, Plot 3, Plot 4` which are not produced before the above output

Comment: What's your question? If you've written some code, then please show us here. If not, then do that first and tell us where you're stuck if you need help.

Comment: Have you given us all variants? So there won't be a `Store C-5`? Etc?

Comment: Just a "order by" SQL can do the job. Did you try ?

Comment: @RoAchterberg i have tried. `CASE
                    WHEN title regexp '^[plot|Plot]+' THEN 0
                    WHEN title regexp '^[shop|Shop]+' THEN 2
                END
                ,LENGTH(title), title`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is all of rows that i have, no other variants

Comment: @KenLee simply order by is not working, i have tried that

Comment: I have posted the SQL result (order by), Please see below.  let's further discuss if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By using "order by" in SQL, it gives you the result you want

Normal SQL:

[image: Unosrted]

After using "ORDER BY" in SQL:

[image: After using "order by"]

Comment: simply order by worked on table, but when i try it using relationship it doesn't work, i have items table linked to accounts table and accounts table has these rows to be sorted, my code is `return $q->join("accounts", "accounts.id",  "=", "items.account_id")->orderBy('accounts.title', 'asc')->get()`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text